# update data grid view automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, grid

I have two windows forms. The first form shows list of records from sql. When you click some cell of a record in `DataGridView` it shows the second form. In the second form you can edit and update the record. I want `DataGridView` to be
updated automatically when user close second form. What should I do?

Comment: What do you think you should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using data bindings, or do you manually fill the grid ? With data bindings its very easy... if the data is contained in a `DataTable` and you change it somewhere, the change will be reflected automatically in the `DataGridView`. It also works with objects that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and lists that implement IBindingList.

If you're not using bindings, you can :

- locate the cell that contains the edited value, and update it manually, OR
- refill the entire grid

Comment: i use Data Bindings and fill this with data set .

Comment: OK, so if your second form works on the same DataSet, the values in the DataGridView will be automatically updated.

Comment: why ? if the second form modifies the data displayed in the first, you should use the same dataset... You can pass it as a constructor parameter for instance

Comment: pas from second form to first form you mean ?
lets explain it more . in second form user can delete a record . if he/she turn back to first form , he/she still can see that record . i want datagridview to be updated , because if user click on that record (which has been deleted) , it will cause error .

Comment: No, you didn't understand me. Both forms have to work on the same DataSet, that way the dataset itself will notify the DataGridView in the first form when a row is added/deleted/modified in the second form. So when you open the second form, you must pass the dataset to it so that both forms use the same dataset

Answer (score 1):

Fill the grid with data from the database again?